# How to implement Email UWP Master/Detail View?

Tags: uwp

Must have the following features

1. On the large screen, both the Master view and the Detail view are displayed
2. **On a small screen, if the Detail view has no content, the Main view is displayed, and if there is content, the Detail view is displayed and the back button can be clicked, when clicked, it will navigate to the Master view**
3. It is responsive

I tried a lot, but can not do the second rule, I need your help :)

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="MiddleState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="920"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainSplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" IsPaneOpen="True" OpenPaneLength="400" DisplayMode="CompactInline" CompactPaneLength="0">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListView/>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame x:Name="DetailFrame"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing your own control you may use the MasterDetailsView control from UWP Community Toolkit. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview).

Comment: It's great for the new developers.

Comment: I believe it's great not only for new devs. You don't have to spend time on basics since you can use already working controls. If you don't need something really special of course.